# How to display chapter header in 1 complete single page

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

How to display content in this form as shown in image1.

[image: image genrated from word for required format]

I am getting my content as shown in image2.
[image: format of text i am getting in latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal compilable example to help use reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage [newlinetospace]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\vfill\filcenter\bfseries}{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter}{10ex}{\Huge}%
[\vfill\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Literature Review\bigskip\\~\&~\bigskip\\ Problem Identification}%
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{sectsty}

    \allsectionsfont{\centering}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Literature Review\newline \hspace*{20mm}\&\newline Problem Identification}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this might answer the question, how do you know that the OP uses `book` and not another class with chapters? And are you sure that you should issue `\allsectionsfont` (affects not only chapters)?

Comment: I used the method given by Biki Teron, it has made change in all my document.     For Chapter 1 used this and it work well

\begin{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\textbf{{\fontsize{300}{310}\selectfont Chapter 1 }}

\vspace{20pt}
\noindent
\textbf{{\fontsize{300}{310}\selectfont Introduction}}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\end{center}


but for chapter 2 it is not aligning text properly in center

Comment: check by using \newline after the Literature Review and same as after \&  @Prachi Agarwal

Comment: No adding \newlinw didn't work
Still thank you
I do this:: 
\begin{center}
 \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
 \textbf{{\fontsize{300}{310}\selectfont Chapter 2 }}
 
 \vspace{20pt}
 \noindent
 \textbf{{\fontsize{300}{310}\selectfont \hspace*{15mm} \vspace*{8mm} Literature Review\newline  \vspace*{8mm}    \hspace*{33mm}\&\newline \vspace*{8mm} Problem Identification}}
 \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
 
\end{center}

Comment: I think using \newline is completely wrong here.