# Incompatibility of scrbook and titlesec when trying to have chapter heading on a single page

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, scrbook

I am trying to display a chapter heading always on a single page with the document class `scrbook`. Gladly, I first found an answer here: [How to display chapter header in 1 complete single page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367885/how-to-display-chapter-header-in-1-complete-single-page)

The answer, however, works only with the document class `book`, but not with `scrbook`. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    % book vs scrbook

\usepackage{lipsum} \usepackage[newlinetospace]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\vfill\filcenter\bfseries}{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter}{10ex}{\Huge}% 
[\vfill\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage] 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{0ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{No Sections with documentclass 'scrbook'}

\section{Comment this out or use documentclass 'book'}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It can only be compiled when i) changing the document class to `book`, or ii) commenting `\section{Comment this out or use documentclass 'book'}` out.

Using `book` as a document class is, due to other reasons, no option for me.

I highly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `titlesec` and `scrbook` don't go along well to begin with.

Comment: To put the last comment another way. `titlesec` is for use with standard classes. `scrbook` comes with own tools to customize chapter and section headings. So yeah, they are incompatible and you should receive a warning about using `titlesec` with `scrbook` in the log-file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies. I forgot about titles and took at the KOMA-script guide. `chapterheadendvskip` does the trick:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    

\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\pagebreak}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pagebreak after this heading}

\section{No pagebreak after this heading}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```